# How to convert a single BYTE element separated by commas to more elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-re

```
with open('out.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    ips = re.findall(b"(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})", data)[0].split(b",")
    print(ips)
```

This part of code opens a file that contains a tons of lines, and this regex finds ips in that file. (I use mmap to avoid a memory error)

This is the list "ips", as you can see has only one element that has ips separated by commas:

```
[b'41.39.180.122', b'192.28.64.246', b'213.82.176.107', b'3.120.158.39', b'5.189.139.56', b'178.128.36.166', b'203.117.94.11', b'5.79.119.182', b'52.48.41.230', b'81.169.129.6', b'178.114.8.24', b'67.20.116.110', b'205.201.139.164', b'180.215.241.68', etc etc ]
```

I tried to use split(b",") but I have this output, the first IP is correctly printed, but then...

```
['41.39.180.122']
[
b
'

8
0

'
,

etc etc
```

Edit (fixed):

```
with open('out.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    ips = re.findall(b"(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})", data)
    ipsn = []
    for ip in ips:
        ip = ip.split(b",")
        ipsn.append(ip)
    print(ipsn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split a bytes object, you need to use a byte delimiter instead of a string one. So instead of `.split(",")` you should use `.split(b",")`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split

Comment: Thanks. But if I add "b" to split, I got the first IP correctly printed, but after that I have printed a letter for every new line. I put the result in the thread.